# Remove logo(header) from embeded external page in worpress website

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to remove the logo or whole header from an external page which is embedded in my WordPress website? I don't where to place `display: none;` in which css.

https://drvoprom.com.mk/vizualizer

Comment: You can't change embedded websites hosted on other domains for security reasons. People would use that for phishing. If you have control over the embedded website, add `?nologo=true` to the URL and code it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Put the display:none as shown in image.
OR

```
.header-classic #Top_bar {
    background-image: url(http://drvoprom.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/header-bg-full.jpg);
    display: none;
}
```

Thank You!

[image: display: none]

Comment: No, I need to remove the logo from the imported external page, bellow on the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #logo {
     display: none !important;
 }
 #pagouni { 
     display: none !important;
 }
```

I have shared with you CSS add this in your style and try.

Most of the iframe CSS will not get changed because all files are serving from another server so you can't overwrite that file.